# Add more enrties to the Filezilla Quickconnect-List

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I want to add more than 10 entries to the Filezilla Quickconnect List.
The 11th FTP host is going to be deleted if I connect to a new one.

Is there any way that every host I connect to can go in this list?

Answer (score 2):

No, the limit of 10 entries is hard-coded.

Of course, FileZilla in open-source, so you can fork it and lift the limit. See `recentserverlist.cpp`:

```c
if (!GetServer(pServer, server) || m_mostRecentServers.size() >= 10)
```

Comment: Yeah, worked :) but you need also to edit this file: if (m_mostRecentServers.size() > 10)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the Site Manager at all?

You connect to any site using the Quick Connect Bar. You then use `File` (menubar) then `Copy current connection to Site Manager…`. You have the benefit of being able to create per-site bookmarks (see `Bookmarks` in menubar) and you can sort/group your sites in any way you like.

In `Edit` (menubar) then `Settings…` page `Interface` you can tick `Show the Site Manager on startup` if you like. The first icon in the toolbar is the Site Manager as well. The arrow next to it or on Linux a simple right-click opens the list of available sites as well.

You can even export your Site Manager items and backup them somewhere.